# Number of ways to tile a W x H Grid with 2 x 1 and 1 x 2 dominos?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

Write a program that takes as input the width, W and height H of the grid and outputs the number of different ways to tile a W-by-H grid with (2x1) dominoes

I know how to solve the problem with 3 x N grid but writing the recursive formula for this is too hard for me!

I have no idea how to do it!

I created two functions F(n) - The complete way of tiling till N and S(n) for number of ways of incomplete tiling for 3 x N ! But here as the height is variable I cannot think of anything

[image]

Constraints : (0 ≤ W+H ≤ 22)

Comment: Simple recursion with memoization and maybe some optimizations should work for `W+H <= 22`.

Comment: Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_tiling ?

Comment: I have looked it @LasseV.Karlsen but the double precision isn't good for me . This is an online judge problem where I should report the exact integral value!

Comment: @IVIad How can we do it ? Can you hint me ? I cannot even think about the state that completely describes the problem!

Comment: I don't really have a better idea other than backtracking on a matrix. Now that I think about it, the trigonometric formula on Wikipedia might also work well for such small values. I'd try that first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is sort of DPish under the hood. The idea is IVlad's: backtracking with memoization.

```
memo = {}


def count_tilings_recursive(uncovered):
    if len(uncovered) & 1:
        return 0
    if not uncovered:
        return 1
    if uncovered not in memo:
        i, j = min(uncovered)
        memo[uncovered] = count_tilings_recursive(uncovered - {(i, j), (i, j + 1)}) + count_tilings_recursive(uncovered - {(i, j), (i + 1, j)})
    return memo[uncovered]


def count_tilings(m, n):
    return count_tilings_recursive(frozenset((i, j) for i in range(max(m, n)) for j in range(min(m, n))))


print(count_tilings(18, 4))
```

The trick here is keeping the number of states from blowing up. First, we always choose the leftmost then topmost square to cover, so that the partial cover can be described as the number of contiguous covered squares in leftmost-topmost order, followed by #rows partially covered, for a total of at most (#rows * #columns + 1) * 2^#rows states. Second, we orient the grid so that there are at least as many columns as rows, bounding the latter number by 10 for interesting computations (because 11 by 11 is trivial).

Comment: Since the dominoes have two squares, we know that either W or H or both are even.  You can always assume that one of the dimensions you are working with is even.  If both were odd, then there would be a single square left untiled.  That will reduce the search space.

Comment: @rossum That's what `if len(uncovered) & 1: return 0` does.

Comment: How to define uncovered area? I am unable to figure it out?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Set of coordinates with no tile yet?

Answer (score 4):

There is a pretty good, general approach to these sorts of problems:

1) Compute the first few values.

```
0  1  0  1  0  1
1  2  3  5  8 13
0  3  0 11  0 41
1  5 11 36 95 281
0  8  0 95  0 1183
1 13 41 281 1183 6728
```

2) Search for those values in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. You can search for a square array by entering the concatenated antidiagonals, or you can do an unordered search for a few large terms. Success: https://oeis.org/A099390 which includes a product formula involving cosines.

As far as I know, there isn't a particularly nice way to do this directly by dynamic programming, say with fewer than exponentially many states in the minimum dimension. There are connections with some advanced mathematics. See the references from the OEIS entry or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_tiling).

---

Kasteleyn's cosine product formula can be implemented with exact arithmetic. In fact, it can be done using dynamic programming.

```
2 cos x = e^ix + e^-ix
```

So, Kasteleyn's product of

```
(4+2 cos 2pi j/(w+1) + 2 cos 2pi k/(h+1))
```

over the range 1<= j <= w/2, 1 <= k <= h/2 can be written as a polynomial in `z=e^i 2pi/((w+1)*(h+1))`, where the exponents can be computed mod `(w+1)*(h+1)` since z^((w+1)*(h+1))=z^0. This product of polynomials can be computed using dynamic programming where you keep track of the coefficients of z^n for each n from 0 through `(w+1)*(h+1)-1`.

```
// part of a C# implementation using a custom CircularVector class
using System.Numerics; // BigInteger

CircularVector cv = new CircularVector(w, h);
cv.setToOne();

for (int i = 1; i<=w/2; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= h / 2; j++)
        cv = cv.multiplyWith(new CircularVector(w, h, i, j));
```

The result is a sum of up to `(w+1)*(h+1)` terms, a polynomial of degree less than `(w+1)*(h+1)` in z. For example, with w=3, h=4, we get

```
{18, 1, 0, 1, 5, 8, 0, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 0, 8, 5, 1, 0, 1}
= 18 + z + z^3 + 5z^4 + 8z^5 + z^7 + 5z^8 + z^9 + 2 z^10 + ...
```

It is necessary to find the integer equal to this polynomialin z. To do this, we can divide the polynomial by the [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) `Phi((w+1)*(h+1))`.

```
// part of a C# implementation 

public static BigInteger[] cyclotomic(int n)
{
    BigInteger[] working = nthRoots(n); // x^n - 1

    for (int i = 1; i<n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            working = polynomialExactDivision(working, cyclotomic(i));

    return working;
}
```

The remainder upon dividing by the cyclotomic polynomial is the (big)integer counting the number of domino tilings of the rectangle. This took 0.014 seconds on one processor to compute the number of tilings of a 20x20 square, 1269984011256235834242602753102293934298576249856, which agrees with the value in [OEIS A004003](https://oeis.org/A004003). The computation can be done in O(w^2h^2) BigInteger additions since you perform about wh multiplications of polynomials of size wh times a factor with 5 terms.

Comment: I  expected OEIS to show a recurrent relation. Well, what I want is specifically a dynamic programming solution or one with no precision issues.? Can you explain how can we solve it via dynamic programming?

Answer (score 1):

Write the relationship between different states, in the code.  The case with height to `2` is equivalent to the Fibonacci sequence.  The case with height `3` can be written with a formula with nine mutually recursive sequences (a bit tedious!), or equivalently with a linear recurrence with a vector of size `9`.

And for `H>=4`, please have a look at this [article](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/18-1/read.pdf).

R. C. Read, A Note on Tiling Rectangles with Dominoes, The Fibonacci Quarterly, 18.1 (1980), 24-27.

Start from the case of the `n * 2` grid.  The number of ways to fill is the `n`-th Fibonacci number.  Why? Because there are two ways to complete the grid on the right end, either with one vertical domino, or with two horizontal dominoes.

Another way to see it is to start from an empty grid, and fill it from left to right.  With this in mind, we can group all the possible incomplete grids according to their "profile" type, that is the boundary on the right side.

For example, for `H=2` case, there are two types of profiles, and for `H=3`, there are nine types of profiles

[image: there are nine profile types for H=3]

(that's from figure 2 in the article).

For the general case, with `H >= 2`, we pre-compute the list of profiles.  Each profile can be encoded by two bit masks.  Note that the first one should not represent a full column, in order to represent without ambiguity.

To enumerate the profile types, while linking them at the same time, we try to place one domino, horizontally and then vertically in the leftmost, lowest cell that is available.  That generates another profile that we add to the list if it's new.  Each profile can be linked to at most two profiles, this way.

[image: recursion for H=3]

See the code below for other choices for `H`.  This process gives us a recursion "formula" between incomplete grid filled with `r` dominoes and those filled with `r+1` dominoes.  It's not really a formula, it's encoded in the `next_profile` dictionary.  It's the equivalent of formula `(1.1)` in the article, for `H=3`.

```python
from collections import defaultdict


def disambiguation(a,b):

    if a == (1<<H) - 1:
        return disambiguation(b,0)
    return (a,b)

def generate_next_profile():

    global next_profile
    next_profile = {}    
    q = [(0,0)]
    done = {(0,0): True}
    while q != []:
        a,b = q.pop(0)
        next_profile[(a,b)] = []
        i = 0
        while i < H and a & 1<<i != 0:
            i += 1
        if i+1 < H and a & 1<<(i+1) == 0:
            c, d = disambiguation(a | 1<<i | 1<<(i+1), b )
            next_profile[(a,b)].append((c,d))
            if (c,d) not in done:
                q.append((c,d))
                done[(c,d)] = True
        c, d = disambiguation(a | (1<<i), b | (1<<i))
        next_profile[(a,b)].append((c,d))
        if (c,d) not in done:
            q.append((c,d))
            done[(c,d)] = True


def count_it(_W, _H):
    W = _W
    H = _H
    result = 0 
    if W * H % 2 == 0:
        u = 0
        v = 1
        num = [{(0,0): 1}, {}]
        n_steps = W * H // 2
        for step in range(n_steps):
            num[v] = defaultdict(int)
            for key, value in num[u].items():
                for pair in next_profile[key]:
                    num[v][pair] += value
            u, v = v, u
        result = num[n_steps % 2][(0,0)]
    return result


WMAX = 10
HMAX = 10

for W in range(1, WMAX):
    for H in range(1, HMAX): 
        generate_next_profile()
        res = count_it(W, H)
        print(res, end = "\t")
    print()
```